# Windchill app - Wizard hangs in infinite loop in IE

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, ptc-windchill

i have the problem that some parts of my windchill app run into infinite loops. the following seems to appear sometimes:
i'm using the wizard and created two steps to add something to a table. the wizard is opened in a popup window and immediately loads the first step.
i already found out that the step defined in the html (div with id "wiz_step_contents") gets loaded into an adjacent tag (div with id "wizard_viewport"). i believe this is caused by extjs.

the first step includes script-tags, so when the step is loaded, some scriptfiles are loaded too.

however, when using fiddler to track the network log, sometimes (and only in IE), those included scriptfiles are loaded infinite times until i close the browser window.

and now to my question: how does windchill load new steps? is there a way a step could be loaded again, say, if some flagvariables aren't set that should be set?

edit: it seems that this is caused by the java fileupload applet... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

JAT, have you tried disabling the Java file upload applet in favor of the Basic Browser functionality? You can set that as a - personal - Preference. QuickLinks>My Settings>Preferences. You would be looking for "File Upload Mechanism".

Comment: this actually works, but (i don't know why) people seem to like the java applet more, so i actually need a workaround...